# Persisting Class Literals in Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

If I have a POJO with a class literal as a field, can I persist it in Objectify?

```
private Class<Foo> fooType;
```

These docs seem to suggest otherwise, but I thought I'd just check to be sure:

http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Properties_and_Value_Types

Answer (score 3):

By default, no.  However, you can fairly easily add a translator that will store a Class as a String natively in the datastore.  You use Class.getName() on save and Class.forName() on load.

Here's an example of what to do in Objectify3:

http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/source/browse/tags/3.1/src/com/googlecode/objectify/impl/conv/joda/DateTimeZoneConverter.java

Note that you return null in individual Converters if the types are not relevant to the Converter.  How to enable it is described here:

http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/source/browse/tags/3.1/src/com/googlecode/objectify/impl/conv/joda/JodaTimeConverters.java

Here's the equivalent in Objectify4:

http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/source/browse/trunk/src/com/googlecode/objectify/impl/translate/opt/joda/DateTimeZoneTranslatorFactory.java

How to enable it is described here:

http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/source/browse/trunk/src/com/googlecode/objectify/impl/translate/opt/joda/JodaTimeTranslators.java

Comment: I like both answers but I think it's gong to be better for OP to know how to create translators so he can persist anything in future.

Answer (score 1):

Objectify can only persist [types supported by the GAE Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Properties_and_Value_Types). Java type `Class` is not one of them.

Also, due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), field `fooType` holds no generic argument information.

Now, there are a couple ways to store `Class` type:

1. Store only the long name of the class, convert via @PrePersist/@PostLoad. The upside of this is that you will get a normal string property that you can query upon.

   ```
   @Transient // tells Objectify to ignore field
   public Class<Foo> fooType;

   @PrePersist
       public prePersist(Entity entity){
       entity.setProperty("fooType", fooType.getName())
   }

   @PostLoad
   public postLoad(Entity entity){
      fooType = Class.forName(entity.getProperty("fooType"));
   }
   ```
2. [Serialize](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#@Serialized) the `Class` (since it implements `Serializable` this is allowed). This will use Java serialization to persist field as a Blob (max 1Mb size). It's a simple solution, but the downside is that the property is not indexed and can not be used in queries.

   ```
   @Serialize
   private Class<Foo> fooType;
   ```